# datasource error with wildfly 9.x

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, wildfly

I add wildfly 9.x with eclipse mars. I am running on jdk 8.
After start the server, I deploy the ojdbc6 jar in the admin console of wildfly.
Then I edit the standalone.xml file and add a datasource as below.

```
<datasources>    
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/jdbc/JNDIName" pool-name="OraclePool" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
     <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</connection-url>
     <driver>oracle</driver>
     <security>
     <user-name>hr</user-name>
     <password>hr</password>
     </security>
</datasource>
<drivers>
      <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle.ojdbc6">
      <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
      <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasrce-class>
      </driver>
 <drivers>
</datasources>
```

When i test connection i get below response,

Internal Server Error

```
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "WFLYJCA0040: failed to invoke operation: WFLYJCA0042: failed to match pool. Check JndiName: java:jboss/jdbc/JNDIName",
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

Comment: When you edit the `standalone.xml` is the server stopped? It's usually best to make configuration changes with CLI or the web console.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the below steps are done at your end:

1. module.xml exists in wildfly-9.x\modules\system\layers\base\com\oracle\main
   with name="com.oracle" - please note that the name is your choice. I have given as mentioned.

2.Configure the Oracle driver reference in the standalone.xml file as below inside the tag

```
<driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle">
                    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
</driver>
```

Here also ensure that the name is matching with the Driver created, e.g. : com.oracle

3. Add the datasource details inside the tag

   ```
   <datasource jndi-name="java:/datasource1" pool-name="datasource1" enabled="true">
          <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:sid</connection-url>
          <driver>oracle</driver>
          <pool>
               <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
               <max-pool-size>5</max-pool-size>
               <prefill>true</prefill>
          </pool>
          <security>
               <user-name>DB_username</user-name>
               <password>DB_Password</password>
          </security>
   </datasource>
   ```

Note : Change your data source username & password according to your DB.

Please restart your server and see how it works.